# How can I know if all child processes have completed after an MPI_Comm_Spawn call ?

Tags: mpi

In MPI, if I spawn children with MPI_Comm_Spawn, the master process performs the spawning. Now the children start doing some work. How do I inform the master and the other parent-level processes that the children have finished?

Comment: How about sending them a message over the intercommunicator? Or using `MPI_BARRIER`, which works with intercommunicators too.

Comment: @HristoIliev: The children know nothing about the Spawn. It's a binary  program I can't change. The children will call MPI_Finalize though.

Comment: Then there isn't much that you can do with MPI as its process control machinery does not provide a way to wait for the spawned processes to simply finish - you get an intercommunicator after the spawn and you are expected to use it in the spawned processes to talk to the parent(s).

Comment: @HristoIliev: Are you implying that there's no way in MPI for a parallel process to spawn another parallel process, wait for it to finish, and then continue?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in the MPI standard (even in MPI-3) that goes beyond starting new processes. Any parent-child synchronisation has to be carried explicitly by MPI communication/synchronisation primitives.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Then I'm in trouble...

Comment: What about the suggestions described here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/282313

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a wrapper around your binary program. Instead of spawning the program directly, spawn instances of the wrapper, which will in turn launch the binary, wait for it to finish, and then communicate with the spawner process.

Comment: not an option. I need the spawned processes to communicate, otherwise I would not use Comm_Spawn.

Comment: @StefanoBorini you can use `MPI_Comm_get_parent` to get an intercommunicator that is able to communicate to the process that calls `Comm_Spawn`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with a wrapper program, as suszterpatt suggested.

Let master be the program that calls `MPI_Comm_spawn`, slave be the program that you want to spawn without modifying its code, and wrapper be the wrapper program.

Let's consider that your slave is itself a mpi program and needs its own communicator to communicate with itself (because you said that in a comment).

- master spawns the wrapper with `MPI_Comm_spawn`.
- wrapper executes the slave binary (maybe with `system`). But without any MPI call (otherwise slave won't get the MPI context).
- slave gets the MPI context created from MPI_Comm_spawn and does its job
- when slave finishes, wrapper signals the end of slave to the master.

I cannot guarantee that my solution respects the MPI standard, but it worked for me with OpenMPI 1.10 on a cluster with a linux environment. It tried with a binary wrapper and wrote files to communicate between master and slave.